# SalesForce SOQL highest number from size column

Tags: salesforce, soql

i'm new to SOQL and SF, so bear with me :)
I have Sales_Manager__c object tied to Rent__c via Master-Detail relationship. What i need is to get Manager with highest number of Rent deals for a current year. I figured out that the Rents__r.size column stores that info. The question is how can i gain access to the size column and retrieve highest number out of it?
[Here is the picture of query i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPrwj.png)

My SOQL code

```
SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Rents__r WHERE StartDate__c=THIS_YEAR) FROM Sales_Manager__c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try other way around, by starting the query from Rents and then going "up". This will let you sort by the count and stop after say top 5 men (your way would give you list of all managers, some with rents, some without and then what, you'd have to manually go through the list and find the max).

```
SELECT Manager__c, Manager__r.Name, COUNT(Id)
FROM Rent__c
WHERE StartDate__c=THIS_YEAR
GROUP BY Manager__c, Manager__r.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

(I'm not sure if `Manager__c` is the right name for your field, experiment a bit)

Comment: Thanks, i also asked at StackExchange SF branch, here is alternative answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/221737/57615